# Kill access to shared folder using cmd (Windows)

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a folder in Windows which allow only 20 simultaneous access. I need a command to kill those connections. Have checked the command `netstat -a` and I can see which users are connected. How to kill those access using cmd? I have tried using taskkil.

Answer (score 0):

net sessions - for list all connections

net sessions \ip /delete /y - for kill a connection